# Is it possible to design a loop such that the car can reach an arbitrarily high speed?

Tags: trackmania-forever

Is there any way to design a loop such that the car can reach an arbitrarily high speed in TrackMania Nations Forever's map editor?

Comment: This is an old question, but I guess having more answers for a great game can never hurt. To clarify, what do you mean by "arbitrarily high speed"? The terminal velocity in free-fall is around 930 km/h if my memory serves correctly. Additionally, are boosters or loops wider than a single piece allowed?

Comment: @mmKALLL  Thanks, "arbitrarily high speed" = one can reach any given speed if one does enough iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trackmania cars all have a hard speed limit of 1000 km/h. You can actually reach this speed on any map by going outside the stadium and doing laps around it on the concrete that surrounds it.

You might need to resort to a technique called speeddrifting to reach the 1000 km/h speed without boosters, though